# Which game is this picture on the SteamOS announcement of?

Tags: game-identification

Recently Valve [announced SteamOS on their site](http://store.steampowered.com/livingroom/SteamOS/).

if you scroll down just a bit under the "Steam is coming to a new operating system" title and paragraph there are 5 pictures of game titles.

I noticed the left-most of them is a picture of a game with (maybe) a "Strategic view" like Knights of Honor, RTW, Europe Total War and so on.

[image: picture from announcement of SteamOS]

Does any one know which game title is the one pictured there?

Comment: You should make a screen capture and post it here, since the steam url that you link may change in the future.

Comment: I was actually thinking of that but did not do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looking at screenshots from google, I'm pretty sure that it's Europa Universalis IV, which is a grand strategy game developed by Paradox.

I even found the original: It's the 6th picture on the [steam page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/236850/) in the picture gallery.

Here they are side by side:

[image]