# Which visual novels are represented by the animated avatars in the 2023 Steam Visual Novel Fest?

Tags: game-identification

Steam is currently running the [2023 Steam Visual Novel Fest](https://web.archive.org/web/20230810191840/https://store.steampowered.com/category/visual_novel), giving out animated avatars of what I assume to be characters from various visual novel games. Which visual novels are these characters from?

These are the animated avatar GIFs:

| Name | Animated Avatar |
| --- | --- |
| Bumpo | [image] |
| Flapjack | [image] |
| Tina | [image] |
| Violet | [image] |
| Mirandi | [image] |
| William | [image] |
| Erickson | [image] |

The names and GIFs are from [SteamDB](https://steamdb.info/app/2540780/communityitems/).

Comment: It's worth noting that these avatars are made by Justin **Erickson** and Mike **Mirandi** (as stated [here](https://steamdb.info/app/2540780/communityitems/)), and 2 avatars share those names. So I doubt they are inspired to any game.

Comment: *what I assume to be characters from various visual novel games* - I don't know if these .gifs qualify as a valid artifact.  Tag guidance: **Only ask if you have a screenshot, video, or audio clip from the game you want to identify** (thus "from the game" isn't satisfied I feel here)

Comment: @TimmyJim We have [multiple well-received game identification questions asking about Steam media — backgrounds, avatars, banners, etc.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgame-identification%5D+steam+is%3Aquestion). E.g., https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/299512/4797, https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/397326/4797, https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/132076/4797, https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/199146/4797, https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/394309/4797, https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/158301/4797, https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/230003/4797.

Comment: Relevant [meta] post about this question: [Are Steam media (avatars, profile backgrounds, banners, etc.) made in celebration of an event valid artifacts for game identification?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16859/4797)

Comment: I really can't find any visual novel nor game having a character named Bumpo or Flapjack, which are pretty uncommon names and a match should be easy to get.