What's that game in the Steam FPS Fest 2024 banner and video thumbnail?
Game in question:

The banner and video thumbnail are of a game with a first-person perspective suggesting a fantasy or medieval setting, with retro-styled pixel art aesthetics.
The scene shows the player character in a medieval castle or dungeon corridor, featuring stone walls, arched ceilings, and wall-mounted torches.
The player's right hand is shown casting what seems to be magic spells, glowing blue energy flames, or orbs, indicating that magic or spellcasting is a game mechanic. The left hand holds a sword or dagger, suggesting the game includes melee combat.
At the top left, a health and magic bar (or stamina) is visible, which implies that the player needs to manage resources during combat. At the top center, a bar with three markers/nodes is shown. On the upper right side, there's a spell or item quick-select UI, featuring a blue flame icon and a sword or dagger, indicating the player can swap between magic abilities and weapons.
I looked through all the ones mentioned in the trailer and did a Google Image search. Alas, I couldn't figure it out.

Since steam is using it as a banner it might just be custom artwork rather than actual game assets.

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas interesting, I never thought of that possibility.

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/403969/which-visual-novels-are-represented-by-the-animated-avatars-in-the-2023-steam-vi they've done it before (at least we think)

The extremely weird aspect ratio of 96:31 (significantly wider than ultrawide) makes me think this isn't a screenshot.  It doesn't look like it was vertically cropped because the GUI is already at the top and the hands are at the bottom.

If this isn't a real game, could it perhaps be inspired by one?

Look at the comments. You can tell your marketing is going great when there are more comments asking the name of a probably fake game than one praising the games that are actually available to play now (and not preorders / early access).

@BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That's not enough reason in itself, as a screenshot can easily be artificially enlarged, especially horizontally.

This game is not real and is pixel art made by an artist working for Steam. Image searching it brings up only the Steam FPS Fest, and the lack of numbers, letters, or understandable UI suggests this is not a functional game.

I'm convinced Man-o-valor is right, but a game that pops up in the comments section of the official YouTube trailer (linked by SPArcheon)—which involves a lot of people fruitlessly asking the same question as the OP—as a potential example for this art is Wizordum:

A Reddit thread dedicated to the same question has users go through a list of old classic RPGs which show some similarities, but none of them come close to the aforementioned Wizordum, which at least has the pixelated look and (apparent) sprite-based game engine (although not 2.5D like the Steam cover art suggests).
